# What's the proper way doing localization in React?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, localization

i used webpack + [StringReplacePlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-webpack-plugin) (see [webpack.config.js#L130](https://github.com/ZibanPirate/zakiii-website/blob/bf02dbdd2473cccb9d2d022174a43da44761ca7a/frontend/webpack.config.js#L130)), this is the result:

English (LTR): https://www.zakiii.com

Arabic (RTL): https://www.zakiii.com/ar

I have one single code, with dictionary.json for each JS file, and configured webpack to handle the localization using StringReplacePlugin. Now i can add any language, Arabic, French, German, Amazigh or even Chinese, just by adding extra entry to the JSON dictionary file.

So this happens on the compile time, which i believe is good for app performance, but it creates an entirely new copy of the app for each language, which results in big bundle size, or multiple chunks if you do lazy loading.

Is there a **proper** way of doing **localization** in React apps (React-dom, not React Native), while keeping **performance** and **speed** in mind?

Comment: You can use this package: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-react`

Answer (score 0):

Use react-i18next. Very easy to use and maintain

Link - https://react.i18next.com/